# Interceptor no getting called retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

Trying add an interceptor to add headers to requests with okhttp3 and retrofit2. I noticed the headers weren't being added to requests and my system.out.println debug line was never getting called. No idea why but here's my code:

creating the service:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        client.newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(new ServiceInterceptor(context))
                .authenticator(new MyAuthenticator(context))
                .build();

        service = (new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build())
                .create(Service.class);
```

ServiceInterceptor:

```
public class ServiceInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final Context context;

    public ServiceInterceptor(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        System.out.println("Interceptor");

        if(request.header("No-Authentication") == null){
            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("User-Agent", "APP NAME")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("access_token", ""))
                    .build();
        }

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Not exactly part of the question but my authenticator is never being called either...:

```
public class MyAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    private Context context;

    public MyAuthenticator(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        //blah blah refresh token here...

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You set `client` to a default `OkHttpClient`.  You create a new client from that client using `newBuilder()`, but don't assign it to anything.  If you aren't using the first client, you should just allocate a builder the first time --

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new ServiceInterceptor(context))
            .authenticator(new MyAuthenticator(context))
            .build();
```

Comment: I had the same issue.  I didn't assign it to a new variable so all configuration settings were lost.  But now that i have assigned it to a variable it works.